# Installing ngx_pagespeed module on Centos error

Tags: nginx, centos, centos6

I am trying to install the PageSpeed module for nginx on Centos 6.
I followed the instructions in [Build ngx_pagespeed From Source](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source)

When i reach to the following command:
`./configure --add-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-release-${NPS_VERSION}-beta`
I get the following error:
`checking for C compiler ... not found
./configure: error: C compiler cc is not found`

Please note: I have gcc installed and up-to-date.

User:
`Linux FontFace 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 13:06:13 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

GCC info:
`gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
gcc-c++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64`

Comment: Did you install all the dependencies listed in your link? It mentions gcc-c++...

Comment: Yes i did.. but i still don't know what's wrong. I have gcc installed in `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: Can you include outputs of `uname -a` & `rpm -qa | grep -i gcc` in your original post please?

Comment: Thanks. Can you try building Nginx without pagespeed?
Use `./configure` without `--add-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-release-${NPS_VERSION}-beta`? Check out this link https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/894

Comment: I did, I get the same error